# Communicating between Processes: Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, signals-slots

I am using PyQt to create the gui for my application and ran into some trouble using threads for seperate processes, so started to use the multiprocessing.Process class. I was, before, using Signals and slots to communicate between the worker process and the gui, but the SignalInstance class can not be pickled and as far as I know cant be used with Process so I am having to find another way to send a progress report (percent done etc) from the worker process to update a progress bar in the gui. what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: What issues did you have that you had to switch from a multi-threaded approach to a multi-process approach?

Comment: the process running in the worker thread was locking up the gui. i posted a question  here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147725/qthread-locking-up-gui-pyside/33172845?noredirect=1#comment54232881_33172845

Comment: Try using [postEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) with a custom event class. You can then watch for your events with, say, an event-filter and update your progress bar from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14135569/5414176) answer, you can share memory between processes using the multiprocessing library. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (see 16.6.1.4. Sharing state between processes).

Comment: it would seem I would need to pass in a Value to the subprocess which will update it as it is working, and I would need to constantly check this value from my gui class and update the progress bar according to the changing value...wouldnt this still lock up my gui?

Comment: I created a 'watcher' class which runs in its own thread. this monitors the Value object and updates the gui which seems to work for me

Comment: It's a good question, I referred to sharing memory between processes in general. I'm pretty sure there's a good way of managing communication with GUI but I don't know what it is, you're welcome to unaccept my answer (if that's possible) or post a new one to get a more specific answer.